# How can I redirect any kind of access to my site to somewhere else, except for me?

Tags: redirects, godaddy, site-maintenance

My site, www.example.com has a MyBB forum installation, and has many users constantly checking it out. I would like to make a major change to it - basically, I want to delete everything it has and start clean.

However, this rebuilding process may take me hours since I need to do a lot of things. Thus, whenever an user tries to enter *any part of my site* (www.example.com, www.example.com/blog etc), the user will always be redirected to www.example.com/underconstruction so they can see a nice HTML site explaining the current situation.

But not only that - while *I* am configuring my site, I need to visit it myself to make sure things do work live. So basically, **it has to redirect everyone who isn't me**.

Is that possible in any way? I am using GoDaddy hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .htaccess!

```
# Turn on mod_rewrite 
RewriteEngine On

# If not your IP address 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^**\.**\.**\.**

# and not the temporary page 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.

# redirect to temporary page 
RewriteRule /*$ /maintenance.php [L]
```

I think the above might help you a whole bunch!

Comment: @Omega No problem. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make backups especially of your database if you are starting over. I'm sure you already will though.

To redirect everyone but yourself you can add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.67.89
RewriteRule /*$ /maintenance.php [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all users except you to a maintenance.php page

Comment: Your RewriteRule only redirects users that access index.php, is that intentional?